# My entire user directory is inside a master branch

Tags: git

I did something on my command line or git that causing my all user directory show up inside a git master branch. When I  open my command line i will see `~ git:(master) ✗` and when I LS it, it would show me a list of my entire user directory on my mac. How I can get to normal command line and get my files out of master branch without deleting them?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `.git` folder. Maybe you created the `.git` folder by `git init` command.

```
$ rm -rf .git
```